# Div element not going to new line in css

Tags: html, css, css-float

Div Tag with ID=content is not going to new line. It is going into header line like this.
[image]

Can anyone please explain why this is happening ?? , and how to put that in new line ?

```
<html>

<head>
<title> Home Page </title>

<style>

#wrapper
{
    width:70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#header .Nav  
{
    width:60%;
    float:right;
}

#header .Nav ul a
{
    margin: 0 3%;
    float:right;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#header .logo
{
    width=40%;
    float:left;
}

.title
{
    float:left;
    width:30%;
}

.main_content
{
    float:right;
    width:70%;
}


</style>


</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper" >

    <div id="header">

        <a href="/" class="logo"><img src="./logo.gif" alt="Zach Woomer" /></a>

        <div class="Nav">


        <ul>

            <a href="./contact.htm">Home</a> 
            <a href="./contact.htm">About US</a> 
            <a href="./contact.htm">Products</a>
            <a href="./contact.htm">Contact US</a> 
        </ul>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="content">

        <div class="title" >
            <h1>This text wraps on the left side and side and side and side </h1>
        </div>

        <div class="main_content">

        </div>

    </div>


</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Well, you have some incorrect CSS `width=40%` instead of `width:40%`. That might be the problem

Comment: It's also my understanding that the ONLY things that can be direct children of a `ul`/`ol` are `li`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding this code to your inline style tag to make the content div appear on its own line:

```
#content {
  clear: both;
}
```

You also have a `width=40%` in your css, so you should fix that as well.

Comment: changing that to width:40% worked .. it was a typo error .. Thanks alot :)

Comment: How to get those unordered list items Contact US, Products , etc .. to be on same horizontal level ?

Answer (score 1):

**[FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/HEXBB/2/)**

I have fixed your problem bro, i hope you can reach something with that.

The `width: 30%;` to `min-width: 30%;`.